# Electric current of inductor

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, inductor, amperage

I have a homework problem that was solved by our instructor:

"Calculate the electric current of the inductor at \$t=0^+\$."

[image]

He calculated \$1/30\$ but the answer sheet was says \$-1/30\$.

Which of them is correct?

Our instructor's work:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us your steps. Is it possible you just defined \$i_{L}\$ in the opposite direction?

Comment: Dear @Null, i dont how type special symbol here, but he calculate finally, iL(0+)=A/L = (1/15) / 2 = 1/30

Comment: Show us *all* the steps, please. And edit your question with the steps rather than putting them in the comments.

Comment: Dear @Null, i edit it.

Comment: What are \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$? You need to define everything for us -- we can't read your instructor's mind. And what is \$A/L\$? What are its units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that both answers are wrong. Imagine if the inductor were omitted from the circuit and any source of voltage or current were applied (via the 3 ohm series resistor) to what is basically a balanced bridge.

What would be the voltage at the junction of the two 1 ohm resistors - it would be the same voltage as at the junction of the two 3 ohm resistors - net voltage across the two points (where the inductor was connected) is always zero.

So, now replace the inductor and ask yourself what the net voltage across the inductor will be - it'll still be zero and never, ever will any current flow thru it.

Comment: Dear @Andy, i add last picture, it's agree with you?

Comment: Yes it does but let other folk have their say for a day in case you or I missed something important.

Comment: i couldn't understand what did you say :)

Comment: Dear @Andy, would you please verify the last solution i added some seconds ago, correct?

Comment: @MichleJordan - I'm not sure what you want me to do. The answer is clearly zero by visual inspection of the problem - no need for any math; it clearly is zero and unambiguously so.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andy. The voltage in the inductor is always 0 V and therefore iL remains at 0 A. The solution of your instructor doesn't make any sense and it's probably for a different problem.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. In the future, this would be better as a comment rather than an answer since it is in agreement with another answer but doesn't add much else. Once you have 50 reputation you will be able to comment everywhere.